# SonarQube 6.7 Coverage widget missing after Sonar analysis

Tags: widget, sonarqube

I've run sonar analysis for C++ and Smalltalk projects. C++ project didn't had coverage report and it still managed to display coverage widget with zero coverage.

When I ran the sonar analysis for Smalltalk project with coverage it didn't even display the coverage widget.

So, how to enable the coverage widget? is it possible to manually enable coverage widget in SonarQube 6.7. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference you're seeing is a result of Executable Lines being fed by the C++ analysis. If SonarQube has *no* coverage data, then the coverage card won't be shown, which is the case with your Smalltalk project. But with your C++ project, the analysis is providing data on which lines *could* (*should*?) be covered by unit tests, and since SonarQube has *some* relevant information it shows the 0% coverage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift response. :)